# iCal iPhone change Exchange calendar color

Tags: iphone, calendar, ical, color

First of all I want ask you how I can change my Exchange Calendar colors to a non-default color.

If I click Calendars in iCal on my iPhone, I get a list of all Calendars. If I click on the blue/white arrow to change the color to *red, orange, yellow, green, blue, purple or brown*. However, this is not the color I'm looking for. I've created an own color in iCal (blue-green combined, like an old GameBoy Color)

Is there any way to set this color in iCal on my iPhone?

If you have any questions about my issue, please ask and I'll update :)

Comment: This is not an Apple fail. It's a Microsoft fail. Specifically, the color is assigned by the Exchange server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On iOS 6 and Office 365 - exchange calendars are fully customizable as long as you like the 7 default colors. :( - **which means, you can't customize the colors on iOS as you clearly stated in the question**

The only interface for changing colors uses the default picker - Go to the Calendar app, tap Calendars in the top left, scroll to the calendar you want to modify, tap the blue circle with the white > symbol and then choose any of the colors that are listed.

Perhaps an update to exchange or to iOS will fix this in the future, but you're not missing anything obvious. Even using alternate apps like Fantastical or Agenda on iOS won't help you escape the limited color palette.

Comment: I tried everything, seems not to work with an Exchange account

Comment: That's an applefail :( Thanks for your reaction. I hope they will fix this in the first future update.

Comment: @Robuust For people that want more options - clearly a fail. For people that want simplicity and 5 colors is enough, it's a win.

Comment: I’m not sure, if this is an Applefail. I think, this isn’t just support with Exchange over EWS(Exchange Web Service) or EAS (Exchange Activ Sync.

Answer (score 0):

I tried everything, seems not to work with an Exchange account

Comment: This is not an answer

Comment: It is an answer, but it's a little on the short and vague (rather than explain in detail) side. It's in essence the same answer as I entered but with less words. Some people will vote one way for terse answers, others the other.

Answer (score 0):

## How to set custom color on iOS ?

Finally after many years I figure out this workaround .

Tested for " iOS 12.5.6 " .

Steps

1. **in " iOS Google Calendar " I choose some color**
2. **in " Apple MacOS Calendar " I choose wanted color**
3. **in " iPhone iOS " system auto sync desired custom color**

Seems like this " combo " trigger right " color change definition ".

Answer (score -1):

The Week calendar app allows you to define a long range of calendar colors, including exchange, google etcetera.